# Using redux-loop with thunk action creators

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I'm using redux-loop to call action creators from my reducers.  This works great normally.

However, I'm also using thunk for some of my action creators.  If I take a regular action creator and convert it to a thunk, it's no longer usable in redux-loop.

Is there a way to call thunks from redux-loop in reducers?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you pass `applyMiddleware` prior to `install` in your enhancers.

```
createStore(reducer, initialState, compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  install()
));
```

`applyMiddelware` will catch actions passed to `store.dispatch()` before redux-loop tries to dispatch them. Right now for the next version of redux-loop I'm planning to have `install()` accept the other enhancers for the store before applying its own modifications so that this doesn't end up being a problem.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to dispatch thunks from actions, because the dispatch action passed to them is not enhanced with the thunk middleware yet. I had to resort to writing my own `loopWithThunk` middleware to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck combining redux-loop and redux-thunk as-is. The problem is that if you you call `applyMiddleware(thunk)` first and redux-loop's `install()` afterwards, actions dispatched by thunks will not have their effects evaluated (because the `dispatch` passed to thunks by the middleware isn't enhanced by redux-loop yet); while if you swap the two around, effects are not able to dispatch thunks (because the version of `dispatch` redux-loop uses for effects is not enhanced with the thunk middleware).

To work around this problem, I needed to write the following pretty hacky store enhancer:

```js
import { applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { install } from 'redux-loop'

export default function loopWithThunk(createStore) {
  let enhancedStore

  const storeSaver = (createStore) => (reducer, initialState) => {
    enhancedStore = createStore(reducer, initialState)
    return enhancedStore
  }

  const thunkMiddleware = () => next => action => {
    return (typeof action === 'function')
      ? action(enhancedStore.dispatch, enhancedStore.getState)
      : next(action)
  }

  return compose(
    storeSaver,
    install(),
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
  )(createStore)
}
```

You can use it like this:

```js
const store = createStore(reducer, loopWithThunk)
```